# What are some interesting features that are common cross-linguistically but don't exist in English?

Tags: english, linguistic-typology, comparative-linguistics

This is on purpose not a very concrete question, I simply want to know some interesting properties other languages have that English doesn't, or features you even think English ought to have, this can be with respect to all linguistic fields you can imagine (grammar, phonetics etc.)

For the correct answer I'll choose the most voted property.

Comment: There are features that are relatively common globally that are missing in most or all of SAE, including English, eg causative, or distinguishing "with" for instruments from "with" for people.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: I guess (I haven't cast a downvote here)  for the same reasons as there are close votes. I admit that I often use close votes and downvotes in combination because this enables some automatic sanitizing scripts.

Comment: And why the close votes?

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer: You have enough reputation to look them up yourself by clicking on the close button (this action itself does not immediately cast a close vote)

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer "…distinguishing "with" for instruments from "with" for people" Amusingly, Lakoff and Johnson (1980) claimed that no language on earth distinguished the two. Evidently they didn't look at anything outside SAE, since even Latin keeps the two distinct!

Comment: I'm pretty sure somebody's going to answer about gendered nouns. English has a few gendered nouns.

Comment: Thanks @jknappen but those are very general buckets.  This question is really the complement of `lists of languages` questions, which are on topic.

Comment: Another unique feature: nil mainstream angst about threats to survival of the language or use as a global language.

Comment: @Joshua Can you name some? A word like "actress" refers to a female actor, but the noun itself has no gender. I'm also not counting the practice of addressing ships as "she".

Comment: @chepner: The only effect of gendered nouns in English is in pronoun selection, so you and I would disagree on whether tigress is a gendered noun or not.

Comment: @chepner "Mother", "father", "daughter", "son", "sister", "brother", etc. How much this counts as grammatical gender depends on your analysis; some people say English has no grammatical gender at all, only semantic gender (since it's not a property of the signifier, it's a property of the signified).

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer Because it's a clear case of an open ended too broad question.

Comment: @AdamBittlingmayer I suspect "features you think English ought to have" my be attracting down/closevotes because it's asking for opinions

Comment: A productive [diminutive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diminutive), which allows you to convert almost any noun into a "diminutive" version. For example, farfalline vs farfalle.

By "productive", I mean a generalizable grammar construct that can be used to produce dimmunitative forms of almost any noun. In contract, English has it to a limited extent, but only as "hard coded" cases, e.g. piglet vs pig.

Comment: But do most languages globally have it?  In IE, certainly.

Comment: See also the non-duplicate but very relevant [What characteristics are unique to Engilsh?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/2427/what-characteristics-are-unique-to-english-or-at-least-rare-among-language-as-a/20994#20994).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'll give the glib answer:

#### A straightforward/predictable orthography.

Out of all the languages which have established writing systems, the vast majority are to some extent phonemic; not all have a one-to-one correspondence between phonemes and graphemes, but it's generally possible to figure out how a word is pronounced, given nothing but its written form.

Only a few languages lack this property; English is one of them. (Others include Mandarin and Japanese—so when I say "only a few", I'm going by number of languages, not number of speakers.)

Comment: Why does this count as an "interesting" property?

Comment: @user6726 Because native English-speakers, in my experience, don't tend to think about it as something unusual—even though it's reached the point that national English-orthography competitions are held in America (spelling bees).

Comment: We have that. It's the text between the slashes in the dictionary. Nobody (including me) actually wants to use it.

Comment: @Joshua I wouldn't call that English orthography, since nobody actually writes that way. It's just a phonemic transcription, like linguists use for any language.

Comment: Is an orthography a property of a language?  It's 1:n or arguably even n:n.

Comment: "Only a few languages lack this property; English is one of them." Semitic languages (and languages like Persian that use an abjad writing system) are another major group, since vowels are mostly not written.Therefore it's not generally possible to figure out how a word is pronounced, given nothing but its written form.

Comment: English orthography is much more predictable as long as you don't think of it as a *single* orthography. Spelling rules are (mostly) consistent *within* a subgroup (Latinate words, Germanic words, French words, etc) but incompatible *between* subgroups. Is it phonetic? No. Is it more regular than it is given credit? Yes.

Comment: @chepner That's a big "mostly" ;) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chaos

Comment: Yep. One word: **Ghoti**.

Comment: I have to disagree on one point: outside of proper nouns, Japanese is extremitusly phonemic, even with the Kanji characters (subclassified into "native"訓読み and "foreign" 音読みreadings). I would add French, actually, to the pile of non-straightforward orthographies. oui oui

Comment: @LarsH As far as I understand (I don't speak any of them), semitic languages *do* have a predictable orthography: if you hear a word, you can write it down. It's the reverse direction (pronunciation of a written word) that is unpredictable. (Compare, for instance, with French, that has almost fully predictable pronunciation but unpredictable orthography).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I see what you mean, that in the strict sense, "orthography" refers to the rules for writing. But those are so intertwined with the rules for reading that it's understandable that we conflate the two. It's clear from Draconis' middle paragraph and first comment that he's including both. Maybe a better phrase than "predictable orthography" would have been "predictable and unambiguous orthography."

Comment: Regarding abjad writing systems, they can have the same unpredictable spelling as other types of writing systems, especially where the alphabet is borrowed from another language. E.g. Persian can use four different letters to write /z/.

Comment: @Carly Logographic writing systems like CJK characters are inherently non-phonetic (and non-phonemic). They often _hint_ at a pronunciation, but their basic function is to express meaning, and there is no direct correlation between form and sound. This is the opposite of phonetic writing systems like alphabets, abugidas and abjads, where the basic function of each glyph is to represent sound, and there is no inherent correlation between glyph and meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's worth mentioning also that Mandarin (one of the cited examples) has Pinyin (and other similar alternatives). Pinyin is so widely adopted / taught that it can be considered essentially a part of the language, albeit not used in general writing. Pinyin is 100% phonetic.

Comment: @JBentley Yes, Pinyin is an alphabetic (thus phonetic) writing system applied to Mandarin, whereas Hanzi is a logographic (non-phonetic) writing system applied to the same language. Any language can, in principle, be represented by any type of writing system; most just happen to only have one type that has official recognition as _the_ orthography for that language.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet It's not as black and white as that (alphabetic = phonetic, logographic = non-phonetic). For example, consider the English "said" vs "paid" where the "ai" is pronounced differently. Then consider the Mandarin 妈 vs 吗 which are both pronounced "ma", derived from the phonetic component 马. Both English (alphabetic) and Mandarin (Logographic) have phonetic and non-phonetic elements. In fact some 80% of Mandarin characters have a phonetic component, and whilst I don't know the %, there is a large volume of English alphabetic words that deviate from the expected pronunciation.

Comment: @JBentley I’m talking only about the _basic_ function of each unit in the system. The entities ⟨a⟩ and ⟨i⟩ have no inherent meaning; they represent only some form of sound (which can frequently be overridden in an orthography like English). Conversely, 马, 妈 and 吗 at the core express only a meaning (horse, mother, question-particle) – their pronunciation could really be anything. Yes, the phonetic component _hints_ at a pronunciation, but that is a bi-product, not the defining feature, and it’s not very reliable: all three are pronounced _differently_ (and even more so 青, 镜, 倩, 锖, 靛, 猜).

Comment: Just a glib rejoinder: spelling is not a property of a language. Just a cultural-historical artifact.

Comment: I joined this SE community just to upvote this. Just today, I told my (native German speaker) son that the "l" is not voiced in "half". Did I mention that you *of course* voice the "l" in German "*halb*"?

Comment: Possibly, the least-phonetic *alphabetic* orthography is [Tibetan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=btn0-Vce5ug).

Comment: @Mitch: What property of a language is not just a cultural-historical artifact? :-)

Comment: @LarsH haha yes. What's a better way to say it? Spelling is invented? Spelling is an afterthought? Spelling is artificial (many meanings of that work) attempt to capture phonology? Spelling is made-up?

Comment: @Mitch Not knowing the ultimate origins of spoken language, it's hard to know how to rightly distinguish them from the origins of spelling. I think most would agree that phonology came first. I guess you could say something like, spelling is typically the collective work of a generally smaller number of generally more educated individuals. But there are many exceptions where the inventions of words and pronunciations come from literate individuals.

Comment: The example of Mandarin is not correct, as (almost) all characters have a single well defined reading.  You can theoretically think of Chinese as a syllabary with thousands of redundant symbols.   This is not just being pedantic, because Japanese has a highly irregular system of reading characters (it goes way beyond merely the onyomi-kunyomi difference).  It happens that there aren't many logographic systems surviving, but in theory a logographic system has no reason to be Chinese-like rather than Japanese-like.

Answer (score 17):

Here are some features that are common to many languages, but absent in English. It's worth taking WALS entries with a grain of salt, but the chapters are great at calling out potential issues and borderline cases and identifying areal patterns.

In no particular order, here are some common features that English does not have.

English does not have [an associative plural construction](https://wals.info/chapter/36).

English does not have [distributive numerals](https://wals.info/chapter/54).

English does not have [productive full or partial reduplication](https://wals.info/chapter/27), according to [this source cited by WALS](https://wals.info/refdb/record/Erickson-2001).

Comment: I'm sure I've encountered reduplication in English.  "Like-like"?  "Super-duper"?

Comment: It's not a big feature of the language, but it's there -- _fancy-shmancy, hoochie-koochie, pussy-wussy_ -- and it's largely pejorative in English.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding precisely what an associative plural is, but I would think English has several: "-ians", "-ists", "-ites", etc.

Comment: @jlawler, WALS cites [this source](https://wals.info/refdb/record/Erickson-2001) for the `No productive full or partial reduplication` feature value for English. I don't know exactly how they're tackling borderline grammatical uses of reduplication (like shm-reduplication and contrastive focus reduplication) that English definitely has and can employ in novel contexts.

Comment: @chepner, an associative plural is a construction like `田中達 (tanaka-tachi)` meaning `Tanaka and her/his associates`, `Tanaka and her/his family`, or something similar.

Comment: OK, yeah, I guess "Tanakian" would more strongly imply a group of followers or adherents, without including Tanaka himself.

Comment: Some more examples of English reduplication: win-win, lose-lose, and many more listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduplication#English . Though, it's possible the original authors mean something specific by 'productive' that we are missing here.

Comment: Does associative plural have to be an affix? We have the phrase "et al" (borrowed from Latin and then abbreviated, of course).

Answer (score 13):

English lacks a simple vowel system: Cross-linguistically, three (/a/, /i/, /u/) or five (/a/, /e/, /i/, /o/, /u/) vowel systems are very common, having a lot of different vowel qualities like English is uncommon.

Answer (score 6):

Tonality. It may seem exotic to English speakers but Yip (2002) says up to 70% of the world's languages may be tonal. I know English has things like record (v) vs record (n) but they are in complementary distribution.

Comment: The distinction of record in english is one of prosody, not tone. (ie. stress or intensity, rather than pitch).

Comment: Isn't it lexical? Additionally, I think that prosodic stress can involve pitch, and tone is not solely, or even necessarily mainly, to do with pitch (Pham, 2004).

Comment: @mango Tone may not be solely to do with pitch (it’s just as often contour-based), but it is often (probably usually) separate from stress. English has lexical and constrastive stress, but not tones; _recórd_ and _récord_ are differentiated purely on the basis of stress distribution.

Answer (score 5):

English doesn't have gendered adjectives, adverbs, or verbs.

There's a debate in comments about gendered nouns, but in no case does English have to match the adjective, adverb, or verb to the gender of the noun. The only time the gender of a noun matters is when you're replacing it with a pronoun.

Example of gendered adjective: the *la* from *la torre* (I think this is Italian; correct me if I'm wrong). In Spanish, the adjective one *uno* is also gendered and appears as *una* if the noun is feminine. But use of *uno* as an adjective is rare as opposed to the adjective *un* which also becomes *una* when pared with a feminine noun.

Comment: *la* and *uno* are articles

Comment: There's only one obscure exception I can think of: *blond man* vs *blonde woman*, and that's because of French.

Comment: @wjandrea: When I went to school, an article was a kind of adjective.

Comment: @wjandrea Similarly fiancé/fiancée, né/née, and so on. All of which are French loans. How much they count is debatable.

Comment: Gendered adverbs are definitely linguistically unusual, I cannot think out of my head of a language having such beasts.

Comment: @Draconis: fiance is stabilizing in English by losing its second e and (more slowly) it's accent. If I weren't on my phone I'd bother with the accent now, but that just demonstrates my point.

Comment: @Joshua It's generally easier to use diacritics with smartphone's keyboard.  Pressing the letter for a bit will open up a list of alternate forms.

Comment: @jknappen: Needed a class that's basically everything but nouns, pronouns, and possessive pronouns.

Comment: @Joshua Articles have never been a kind of adjective in any language that I know of, certainly not English.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: Considering this literally depends on which elementary grammar book you had, this is a pointless debate.

Comment: @Joshua Elementary grammar books frequently get basic grammar very wrong (nouns are not ‘thing words’ and verbs are not ‘activity words’ as I recall my own elementary grammar books from second grade saying). No serious grammar book of English will classify articles as adjectives for the very simple reason that they behave **completely** differently.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Determiners are different from adjectives, true, but in ways that certain classes of adjectives are different from other classes. True, they are not gradable and have no comparatives or superlatives, but this is true of some adjectives, too. The words of the phrase "What an ugly old black silk top hat" have only one idiomatic order. Each modifier has to occupy a specific slot. The determiner slot is just one of several. The notion that determiners are one of several contrasting classes of adjectives is not so easily dismissed, I think.

Comment: @Rosie But articles especially _are_ different from adjectives in ways classes of adjectives are not internally. If you go by CGEL, adjectives have three core properties: _function_ (attributive, predicative, postpositive), _gradability_ and _dependents_ (modified by adverbs). Not all adjectives have all three, but the articles have **none**. Adjectives also don’t inflect for number (the indefinite article does) and, being modifiers, their slots are inherently optional (the determiner slot is not). There’s a reason modern linguistics moved away from classifying determinatives as adjectives.

Comment: @Rosie And even when it was common to call determinatives ‘restricting adjectives’ and things like that, the articles were usually still kept separate.

Comment: @JamusNahsJacquet: Thank you. My English grammar textbooks were really old.

Answer (score 5):

English doesn’t use [infixes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix) (except for a few colloquialisms where an infix is created for comic emphasis, like fan-bloody-tastic or abso-fragging-lutely).

Comment: Why the downvotes? Are infixes not common in other languages?

Answer (score 1):

English does not double its negations. The correct interpretation of a sentence with two negatives really should cancel them out. You may have heard "I ain't got no satisfaction." It's deliberately incorrect for effect. While the author may well insist on a simple meaning, formal English demands the opposite of what the author intended, *and this is very important to formal language* that it behave this way. Complex electrical controls and option contracts would be very difficult to describe without this property.

Spanish on the other hand stacks its negatives. It doesn't take too long to get used to in general conversation and literacy but I can't imagine using it for technical work.

Some kinda source: [Double Negatives in Spanish](https://www.thoughtco.com/double-negatives-spanish-3079432)

Comment: Not so.  This is a prescriptivist’s unsuccessful attempt to impose a bogus requirement on English.  Belongs in the bin next to what you don’t end a sentence with.  Though I agree with the logic of it for avoiding arguments in critical applications.

Comment: This is called "negative concord", as it applies to more than just two negatives, and is a feature of many dialects in both the UK and the USA, just not the standard dialects of either country. Although Jagger wrote his lyrics in imitation of lyrics written by black American blues musicians, he wouldn't have needed to learn negative concord from there.

Comment: Negation is much more complex than that; not all negatives cancel out.

Comment: What nonsense is this? You're saying languages like Spanish or Italian aren't suited for talking about "technical work". That is beyond prescriptivist, that's some whack theory of language superiority. It's not true. Hence my downvote.

Comment: ObJoke: [Can a double positive form a negative?](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=324371)

Comment: @Barmar: I tell that one; however decomposing fixed idioms yields madness.

Comment: @WGroleau Are those really comparable? Negative concord really is unidiomatic in many common English dialects, including the standard ones. P-stranding is idiomatic in all dialects.

Comment: I said no such thing.  Double negative in Spanish is not ambiguous; it’s still negative.  In English, the long unsuccessful attempts by prescriptivists to ban it are what makes it possible for pedants to argue the speaker meant something other than they meant.  And IF I were to rate any language as “superior,” it wouldn’t be English.

Comment: https://www.chicagotribune.com/news/ct-xpm-2006-11-08-0611070296-story.html  Putting math rules on a language is silly.  And I did not say it avoids ambiguity; I said it avoids arguments.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Even if negative concord is ungrammatical in many dialects, it absolutely *never* turns the meaning of a sentence positive, in any dialect (AFAIK). So people who pretend to be confused and think "I didn't do nothing" means "I did something" are just lying.

Comment: @BrennanVincent That's not really true. For example, in the exchange "I'll bet you did nothing to help." "I didn't do *nothing*.", the double negative is clearly intended to create a positive sense. I'm not sure whether that construction can work that way in languages with negative concord.

Comment: Fair enough; the emphasis on *nothing* changes the meaning.

Comment: @eyeballfrog your example is not a negative concord or double negative; *nothing* in that sentence is a noun. It's the same part of speech as *something* here: "I'll bet you did a chore to help." "I didn't do a chore."

Answer (score -3):

I am always surprised that there is no English word that is equivalent to French neuf (new to you or revised but not brand new (newly made)). For example in English someone can buy a "new used" car.  I assume that other romance languages have a neuf word.

Comment: If you're going to make this argument, then there are literally _thousands_ of words that can be chosen.  The reverse is also true (for example, may languages use complex phrasing to express the same concept of possession that English expresses in the single verb 'to have').

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as it has been asked. The OP is looking for cross linguistic features, not single words in single languages. Also, this is a meaning of a single word, not a feature of French as a whole.

Comment: Also FYI you have it backwards: neuf/neuve means new (not used) whereas nouveau/nouvelle means new (to you or revised). So you'd say `nouvelle voiture` for your new (latest) car and you'd say `voiture neuve` for a brand new car with 0 miles. A `voiture neuve` would typically be from the `nouveau modèle`, i.e. the new (latest) model.